# How to use superscripts in QDoubleSpinBox suffix

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, superscript, qspinbox

I am trying to format part of a suffix in a QDoubleSpinBox as a superscript.
Thus far I have tried the following:

```
self.myDblSinBox.setSuffix("Nsm<sup>-4</sup>")
```

and:

```
self.myDblSinBox.setSuffix(r"Nsm$^{-4}$")
```

but without succes. Is there anyone who knows if this is possible?
I am using Python 3.6, IPython 6.1, Spyder 3.2.3, and PyQt5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [unicode superscript characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscripts_and_subscripts_block) for this:

```
self.myDblSinBoxsetSuffix(' Nsm\u207b\u2074')
```

[image]